# SQLAlchemy: Use column from outer query in subquery

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

### My issue

I have this (MSSQL) query which I'd like to convert to SQLAlchemy:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Artikel AS root WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Artikel WHERE Artikel.MM_ParentID = root.ROW_ID) = 0 AND MM_ParentID = 0;
```

This is what I tried:

```python
root = sqlalchemy.orm.aliased(GSDArtikel, name='root')
parent_count_query = gsd_session.query(sqla.func.count()).select_from(GSDArtikel).filter(GSDArtikel.MM_ParentID == root.row_id)
results = gsd_session.query(root).filter((parent_count_query == 0) & (root.MM_ParentID == 0))
```

However, `parent_count_query == 0` generates a bool, which makes this fail:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'BinaryExpression'
```

`parent_count_query` has the type `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query`.

I also tried adding `.subquery()` which changes the type to `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Alias`, but still gives me `False` when comparing it.

When I print the generated inner query, it doesn't quite look like I'd expect it to:

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM [Artikel], [Artikel] AS root 
WHERE [Artikel].[MM_ParentID] = root.row_id
```

I also tried using `sqla.and_(parent_count_query == 0, root.MM_ParentID == 0)` instead of `&` - then I don't get a `TypeError`, but instead get the following SQL for `results`:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM [Artikel] AS root 
WHERE 0 = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

### The big picture

I have a table with root and children rows, which basically looks like this:

```
| row_id | MM_ParentID |
------------------------
| 1      | 0           |
| 2      | 0           |
| 3      | 0           |
| 4      | 1           |
| 5      | 1           |
| 6      | 3           |
```

What I'm trying to find is all rows which are parents (`MM_ParentID == 0`) and have no children (subquery which gets all children with `MM_ParentID` equal to the `row_id` of the current item returns 0 rows). So in this case, the item with `row_id` 2 would be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simplifying the query so it joins the children to the parents and then gets the ones where the child `IS NULL`:

```python
stray_parents = (gsd_session.query(item)
                 .outerjoin(child, item.row_id == child.MM_ParentID)
                 .filter(item.MM_ParentID == 0, child.row_id == None))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you cannot build a subquery in `sqlalchemy` and then just compare the result as you would do in pure `SQL`.

Anyway, if I've understood correctly your problem, I would tackle it in a different way; first fetching the Articles that do have a parent,

```
In [39]:
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
root = aliased(Article, name='root')
subq = session.query(Article.id).select_from(Article).filter(Article.parent_id == root.id)
print(subq)

SELECT article.id AS article_id 
FROM article, article AS root 
WHERE article.parent_id = root.id
```

And then looking for the root articles like these:

```
In [40]:
from sqlalchemy import tuple_
results = session.query(Article).filter(~Article.id.in_(subq))
print(results)

SELECT article.id AS article_id, article.parent_id AS article_parent_id 
FROM article 
WHERE article.id NOT IN (SELECT article.id AS article_id 
FROM article AS root 
WHERE article.parent_id = root.id)
```

For sure there are other ways; this is the simpler I've figured out, probably not optimal if your table is very big. (And sorry that I've used different spelling for your table and column names!)

Hope it helps.